# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 In the most simple program

Tags: java, arrays

I'm new to Java. this just the 2nd program i've tried to build.
i tried to find the answer in prevoius questions, but couldn't , forgive me if this was already answered.

this is the program:

```
public class UseThree {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Hi, ");
        System.out.print(args[2]);
        System.out.print(", ");
        System.out.print(args[1]);
        System.out.print(", and ");
        System.out.print(args[0]);
        System.out.println(".");
    }
}
```

Somebody can tell me why i can't run this?

the problems it shows are:

```
run UseThree

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

    at UseThree.main(UseThree.java:7)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

Comment: You have to pass some arguments (at least 3) when running your program.

Comment: @ZouZou Two arguments would suffice. (One is the filename.)

Comment: @devnull That is actually not the case, if you don't pass any arguments, the array length is 0.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't pass any command line arguments to your program, you won't have anything in the `args` array. Before accessing the array, you could check how many arguments you actually received, e.g.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("received " + args.length  + " arguments");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This exception occurs while you are accessing an element with out existence.For this program you need to at least pass 3 command line arguments. Bcz you used

arg[0],arg[1],arg[2]

Answer (score 0):

You have to add string values for arg[] when you run the code that is:

```
java UseThree name1 name2 name3
```

name1 pertains to arg[0], name2 to arg[1] and name3 to arg[2].

Answer (score 0):

Well u did not got what actual thing is just do one thing that print the length of the args and the see the length and get idea form that.

that will give u idea :)

```
public class TestingProject {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.print("Hello,HiHow,you");
        System.out.println("Hello1"+"Hi1"+"How1"+"you1");
        System.out.println(args.length);

    }

}
```

remember in that what is @param args then u will get your ans :)